# Cross_val_predict: Getting predicted values and predicted probabilities in one step

Tags: scikit-learn, prediction, cross-validation

Following example script outputs the predicted values and predicted probabilities:

```
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X = diabetes.data
y = diabetes.target
lg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(random_state=0, solver='lbfgs')
y_prob = cross_val_predict(lg, X, y, cv=4, method='predict_proba')
y_pred = cross_val_predict(lg, X, y, cv=4)

y_prob[0:5]
y_pred[0:5]
```

I tried following without success:

```
test = cross_val_predict(lg, X, y, cv=4, method=['predict','predict_proba'])
```

**Question:** Is there a way to get both predicted values and predicted probabilities in *one step*, without running cross-validation twice? Also, I have to make sure that the values and probabilities correspond to the same input data.

Answer (score 5):

The values of `y_pred` can be derived from `y_prob`:

```py
# The probabilities as in the original code sample
y_prob = cross_val_predict(lg, X, y, cv=4, method='predict_proba')

import numpy as np
# Get a list of classes that matches the columns of `y_prob`
y_sorted = np.unique(y)
# Use the highest probability for predicting the label
indices = np.argmax(y_prob, axis=1)
# Get the label for each sample
y_pred = y_sorted[indices]
```

Now, it may happen that `y_pred` from `cross_val_predict` does not match the `y_pred` here in all cases. This happens, when there are multiple classes with identical highest probability, as is the case in your sample code. For example, the predicted probabilites are zero for all classes for the first sample. Anyway, it seems to me, that logistic regression (which is, in fact, classification) is not suitable for the diabetes dataset.

For the rationale of `y_sorted` see the [`cross_val_predict`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) docs:

> method : string, optional, default: ‘predict’
>
> Invokes the passed method name of the passed estimator. For  method=’predict_proba’, the columns correspond to the classes in sorted order.